# How do I use a "Mustek BearPaw" scanner?

Tags: 12.10, scanner

I own a **Mustek BearPaw 2448CU Pro II** scanner. How do I use it with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Open `Simple Scan` software and connect your scanner, it will detect the scanner and you will able to scan the documents. If the software not detecting the scanner you need to install the driver for it.

Here is the link for downloading driver for "SANE Mustek USB2 backend (driver) for Mustek BearPaw 2448 TA Pro USB scanner"
http://www.meier-geinitz.de/sane/mustek_usb2-backend/

Comment: Thanks, but `simple scan` dont find the scanner and drivers I cant find nowhere.. Maybe you know where is the drivers?

Comment: Try the above mentioned drivers.

Comment: I've tried to install it.. It was not success.. :(